# How to subscribe to or access Tridion stack exchange questions?

Tags: discussion

I want to view Tridion stackexchange questions in my inbox or web page through .NET API or Web Services. Is this possible? How would you go about it?

Answer (score 5):

I created a filter here: http://stackexchange.com/filters/34648/tridion-stuff

You can subscribe to it via [RSS](http://stackexchange.com/feeds/tagsets/34648/tridion-stuff?sort=active) or Email via the form on the right

It includes all Tridion questions across the Stack Exchange platform.

Answer (score 2):

Another possible way is to use [OData](http://www.odata.org/) endpoints. You can query using it. Some details
http://data.stackexchange.com/about

Even you can query OData using [LINQPad](http://coderjournal.com/2010/06/using-linqpad-to-query-stack-overflow/)
But unfortunately i could not found OData Url for this site, could be because its in Beta.

Please try to find out the URL if it make sense to you. Usual format for this is

```
 http://data.stackexchange.com/<community>atom
 http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/atom
```

Answer (score 1):

You can hover over the tags on any Stack Exchange site to subscribe to them. I [posted about this somewhat obscure feature on my blog](http://www.createandbreak.net/2013/05/subscribe-to-functional-or-technical.html) (with screenshots!).

You could also geek out with Bart Koopman's [Tridion dashboard/StackOverflow extension](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/dashboard-extension) and adapt it to Tridion Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar filter to Chris's: http://stackexchange.com/filters/38484/tridion

There is also a twitter account that tweets the questions automatically: https://mobile.twitter.com/stacktridion you could use the twitter api to query it.